# Fatal error when trying to start postgresql container in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, containers

I'm deploying Dataverse using docker.

The containers were working nicely, however, few days ago and without any changes, when I use docker-compose up -d the db container (postgresql) does not start. This is the error when use docker logs db.

```
PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
LOG:  could not create IPv6 socket: Address family not supported by protocol
FATAL:  could not open directory "pg_tblspc": No such file or directory
LOG:  database system is shut down*
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

What is the contents of the PGDATA directory and are you able to share the docker-compose section of the database?

According to your logs, one of the important directories underneath PGDATA is missing. This can happen if the data is not persisted in general and only the empty `data` directory is given. I assume that you have a volume mounted to the docker image. So showing the contents of that directory (PGDATA) will help us understand if only `pg_tblspc` is missing or everything.
If it is only `pg_tblspc`, we already have threads that discuss a recovery on SO. I don't know the reason, but understanding what exactly is missing (pg_tblspc or everything) would be important to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when restart my container:

```
ERROR: could not open file "pg_tblspc/18684/PG_9.6_201608131/16385/26851": No such file or directory
```

Inspecting the container internally, I found the following:

```
├── pg_tblspc
│   └── 18684 -> /var/lib/postgres/pg_dirs/pg_indices
```

In my docker-compose configuration I only had the volumen:

```
volumes:
      - postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

so when restart the container all data referenced for `18684 -> /var/lib/postgres/pg_dirs/pg_indices` is lost

to avoid this issue, I add this path to the volumes like this:

```
volumes:
      - postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - postgres/pg_indices:/var/lib/postgres/pg_dirs/pg_indices
```

The above does not restore the already lost data,(I had to restore my entire database), but prevents further loss